# Escape to Clear Search with other JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I am using the following code to insert an X in a search bar that clears text. I also inserted a snippet to submit upon Return. I would now like to add a snippet to clear the search & submit upon Esc. (which == 27). Any ideas?

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/PyF6e/)**

```
<input type="text" id="fac" name="fac" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input clearable" placeholder="Search">
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

  function tog(v){return v?'addClass':'removeClass';} 

  $(document).on('input', '.clearable', function(){
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
  }).on('mousemove', '.x', function( e ){
    $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth-18 < e.clientX-this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');   
  }).on('click', '.onX', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('');
fnexec(3);
  });

});

$('#fac').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fnexec(3);
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is the CSS in case anyone wants to use the X part for themselves - it's pretty nifty!

```
.clearable{
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/z7ZSYjt.png) no-repeat right -10px center;
  padding:3px 18px 3px 4px; 
  border-radius:3px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
.clearable.x{
  background-position: right 5px center;
}
.clearable.onX{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: why not just use an "<input type=search>" instead of re-inventing the clear button on a text input?

Comment: Oops - I'm an idiot. That got Escape to clear the text. I still couldn't get Escape to resubmit, but I just figured it out. I was so stuck on my stupidity that I thought something else was wrong. Once my brain was on straight, I figured out I had to use keyup instead of keypress. 

I have updated the JSFiddle. Thank you, Dan!